# Make an array larger LISP

Tags: arrays, lisp, common-lisp

I have an array in LISP i need to make it lager without modifying it

For instance:
`(1 2 3 4)` size=4

I would like

`(1 2 3 4 NIL NIL)` size=6

How can I do it ? I have thought of `make-array` again and copy the previous element of the "old" array

Thanks

Comment: Which lisp are you using? If Common Lisp, then you can do the array “adjustable" and increase its size without problems. See the [manual](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mk_ar.htm#make-array).

Comment: have you tried googling for e.g. "CLHS copy-array"? it shows copy-seq, make-array, etc.

Comment: Yes Common LIsp

Comment: These are not arrays, these are lists -- very different beasts. Please clarify what you are working with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
> (defparameter a1 (make-array 4 :adjustable t :initial-contents '(1 2 3 4)))
> a1
#(1 2 3 4)
> (adjust-array a1 6 :initial-element 0)
#(1 2 3 4 0 0)
```

Comment: btw., it might be useful to give an initial element to `adjust-array`. That there is `0` used to fill in the new slots in the vector is implementation specific bahavior.

Comment: Hmm, I just tried it, but as hypertext also points, we cannot use :initial-contents and :initial-element at the same time :/

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways of doing this, which one to choose depends crucially on what you want.

If you want to change an N-element array[*] into an N+2-element array, you can use `[vector-push-extend][1]` with suitable arguments. If, that is, the element-type if your array is compatible with adding a `NIL`.

If you don't want to modify the original array, you can use a combination of `make-array` and setting elements explicitly. Again, depending on the element-type of the array, you may be unable to "extend" it with `nil` elements.

[*] I will for the moment assume "one-dimensional array"

Answer (score 1):

```
(append '(1 2 3 4) '(NIL NIL))
;; => (1 2 3 4 NIL NIL)
```